# Can't access 'params' or 'auth' in Cloud Function triggered in Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I asked this in the Firebase Google Group but think that's actually the wrong place so I'm reposting here. Hope that's OK.

The EventContext for Firebase Cloud Functions is pretty well described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext). There it says that with an event triggered on a Firestore create at `messages/{messageId}` I should be able to...

```
def process_message(event, context):
    # What's in the context?
    print(dir(context))

    # Can I access 'messageId'?
    print(context.params['messageId'])
```

No luck - `context.params` doesn't exist, and `dir(context)` returns `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'event_id', 'event_type', 'resource', 'timestamp']` - definitely no `params` in there.

The docs also suggest that `context.auth` is available on Realtime Database triggers, but not Firestore? This is a shame as it would be really useful for securing functions.

Am I missing something here? Can anybody help me access `context.auth` and/or `context.params` in a Cloud Function written in Python and triggered by Firestore?

Thanks.

Comment: "The docs also suggest that context.auth is available on Realtime Database triggers, but not Firestore?" That is correct, the `context.auth` value is only available for RTDB triggered functions. "This is a shame as it would be really useful for securing functions." Agreed, although commonly the user can be derived from the data they write. Feel free to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) or add your vote to the [existing feature request on github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/300).

Comment: That's useful, thanks. Hopefully it will be implemented soon. Any idea on 'params'?